# remove duplicate of specific value of object in array reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a object array that has a value like this

```
[
    {
        username: 'Goku',
        hero: 'superman',
        power: 'laser',
        isMasked: false
    },
    {
        username: 'Gohan',
        hero: 'batman',
        power: 'brain',
        isMasked: true
    },
    {
        username: 'Goten',
        hero: 'cyclops',
        power: 'laser',
        isMasked: true
    },
    {
        username: 'picollo',
        hero: 'superman',
        power: 'streangth',
        isMasked: false
    },
    {
        username: 'bulma',
        hero: 'batman',
        power: 'rich',
        isMasked: true
    },
    {
        username: 'brolly',
        hero: 'jin',
        power: 'laser',
        isMasked: false
    }
]
```

As you can see, the array contains a json that has a different heroes, some of them have a same power, but the problem is, some user had a same heroes, what I want to do is that I want to remove those objects inside my array that contains a same heroes as others, so that the output will be

```
[
    {
        username: 'Goku',
        hero: 'superman',
        power: 'laser',
        isMasked: false
    },
    {
        username: 'Gohan',
        hero: 'batman',
        power: 'brain',
        isMasked: true
    },
    {
        username: 'Goten',
        hero: 'cyclops',
        power: 'laser',
        isMasked: true
    },
    {
        username: 'brolly',
        hero: 'jin',
        power: 'laser',
        isMasked: false
    }
]
```

As you can see, users with the same hero as another is removed, and the array only contains objects with unique heroes, I'm using reactjs as my JavaScript framework, how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
const removeDuplicateByKey = (arr, key) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    //Found duplicate value
    if (acc.find(el => el[key] === val[key])) {
      return [...acc];
    }
    return [...acc, val];
  }, []);
};
```

I have also created a demo [check it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/n9nvr6y7z0).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in following steps:

- Apply `reduce()` on `arr` and set `ac` initially  to `[]`.
- Inside `reduce()` check if `ac` have any obj whose `hero` is equal to current object.
- If yes then return `ac`.
- If no then return `ac` along with new item.

```js
var arr = [ { username: 'Goku', hero: 'superman', power: 'laser', isMasked: false }, { username: 'Gohan', hero: 'batman', power: 'brain', isMasked: true }, { username: 'Goten', hero: 'cyclops', power: 'laser', isMasked: true }, { username: 'picollo', hero: 'superman', power: 'streangth', isMasked: false }, { username: 'bulma', hero: 'batman', power: 'rich', isMasked: true }, { username: 'brolly', hero: 'jin', power: 'laser', isMasked: false } ];

let res = arr.reduce((ac,a) => ac.find(x=> x.hero === a.hero) ? [...ac] : [...ac,a],[]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Array#reduce`. Push the object to a new Array if the hero value does not exist.

```js
var arr = [ { username: 'Goku', hero: 'superman', power: 'laser', isMasked: false }, { username: 'Gohan', hero: 'batman', power: 'brain', isMasked: true }, { username: 'Goten', hero: 'cyclops', power: 'laser', isMasked: true }, { username: 'picollo', hero: 'superman', power: 'streangth', isMasked: false }, { username: 'bulma', hero: 'batman', power: 'rich', isMasked: true }, { username: 'brolly', hero: 'jin', power: 'laser', isMasked: false } ];

var res = arr.reduce((a, b) => a.map(i => i.hero).indexOf(b.hero) > -1 ? [...a]:[...a,b], []);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below function as it work for me.

```js
function removeDuplicateByKey(arr,key) {
  let uniqueObj = {};
  let filterArr = arr.filter(obj => {
    if (!uniqueObj[obj[key]]) {
      uniqueObj[obj[key]] = 1;
      return obj;
    }
  });
  return filterArr;
}
```

you can call this fun as removeDuplicateByKey(array,'hero')